# Can't find database engine in ssms 2014

Tags: ssms

I have been stuck on this for hours so any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. I am also new to back end development.

I reformatted my computer yesterday, so that I can install ssms 2014 and visual studios 2012 on a fresh computer. However when I open ssms 2014, I cant find a database engine. I remember before I reformatted my computer, I connected to something similar to 'SQLEXPRESS' (dont rmb the exact name).  How can I create a new local database engine ????

thanks,

Ryan Wong

Comment: Did you install the database engine or just the SSMS tools? Try connecting to .\sqlexpress.